# How to call java built-in TimSort on an array of primitive data types

Tags: java, sorting, quicksort, timsort

In java, The method [`Arrays.sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) has two overloads (that I am interested in, in this post) one is for primitive types and the other is for reference types. They use different sorting algorithms.

How can I use the algorithm used for reference types to sort primitive types (without converting them to reference types neither using lists)

The method [`Arrays.sort(int[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-int:A-) uses Dual-Pivot [Quicksort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort).

The method [`Arrays.sort(Object[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-java.lang.Object:A-) uses [TimSort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort).

If I have an `int[] array = { /* some values here */ };` , How can I sort it using TimSort?
(I know that using `Integer[] array = { /* some values here */ };` will use TimSort but I do not want that because of the overhead of using Objects instead of primitive data and there might be some boxing and unboxing later)

Or is it not efficient to use TimSort on primitive data?

I had found a class for TimSort [java.util.TimSort](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/TimSort.java) but I couldn't access it in my codes.

The reason for this question is that Quicksort has a worst case of `O(n^2)` and I had faced an array that exploited that case. While TimSort has a worst case of `(n log(n))` and a best case of `O(n)`

UPDATE:

I am actually interested in just having a built-in method for TimSort, it does not need to be `Arrays.sort`. If there is any other built-in method to sort primitive data types using TimSort it is totally welcome.

Comment: Can you show that array you faced which exploited the O(n^2)? And how did you come to face it?

Comment: @HeapOverflow sure. I had submitted a code for a problem in programming training website ([codeforces](https://codeforces.com)), The algorithm is sure to be correct, but The 4th test for my code had exceeded the allowed time using int[]. The input array is too long (200000 element) and the website does not view all of it (only 72). You can see the case [here](https://codeforces.com/contest/1165/submission/73344821) at the bottom of the page there is a "Click to see test details"
[Another submission](https://codeforces.com/contest/1165/submission/73356684) that used Integer[] had been accepted

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I highly doubt the problem setter intentionally created a worst case order for a specific sort algorithm, and it should be hard to create one unintentionally. So I'm not convinced it actually is one. But the test case doesn't look random, so I'm thinking rather than a particularly bad case for Quicksort it might be a particularly good case for Timsort. Hard to say without seeing the complete data.

Comment: Ok, I got the `int` version easily accepted simply by storing the numbers differently: `contests[(i + 123456) % contestCount] = in.nextInt()`. So I guess the input is indeed somehow particularly bad for Java's quicksort.

Comment: I had found links that say that this is highly intentional: [most of the time problem setters like to make such test cases](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-handling-tle-while-using-arrays-sort-function/), 
[if there is an anti-quicksort test](https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/46756), 
[there is anti quick-sort test case](https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/12833)

I have notice this pattern in the test case: low value, higher value, higher value, increase by one, and the difference between two adjacent increase-by-one patterns is constant `4`
for example: 199995 199996 .... 199991 199992

Comment: That geeksforgeeks article is unbelievably terrible and wrong. In general, yes, as a problem setter you do include test cases that break *bad* sorting algorithms, but *not* cases that break *reasonable* sorting algorithms. You don't punish people for doing the right thing, using the library's sorting function. Can't really judge the codeforces discussions and don't have time to follow the references in them, but I suspect/hope it's more of a rumor/misunderstanding.

Comment: I know this is late, but the reason not to use Timsort for primitives is that in practice comparison is so cheap that the costs of a sophisticated data structure will exceed it.

Answer (score 0):

java built-in `TimSort` and `ComparableTimSort` do not work with arrays of primitive data types, it's only sort method expects array of objects

```
static void sort(Object[] a, int lo, int hi, Object[] work, int workBase, int workLen);
```

While `DualPivotQuicksort` has sort methods for primitive types, like:

```
static void sort(char[] a, int left, int right,
                 char[] work, int workBase, int workLen);
static void sort(int[] a, int left, int right,
                 int[] work, int workBase, int workLen);
```

Update. Although it's not the answer for original question about `Arrays.sort`, [geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/timsort/) has implementation of timsort for c++/java/python3/c#. Method prototype for java is:

```
public static void timSort(int[] arr, int n);
```

Comment: While I couldn't find, but there might be some other implementation somewhere else in java library that accepts primitives (I hope). I will wait for some other answers before marking your answer as a solution if no answer found such a method.

Comment: I am actually interested in just having a built-in method for TimSort, it does not need to be Arrays.sort. If there is any other built-in method to sort primitive data types using TimSort it is totally welcome. I will update the post to clarity this point.

Comment: Do you mean: built into jdk/jre?

Comment: Right. A method that java provide, not a method that I write (or copy paste it)